# config and set up LDAP authentication server for my elasticsearch plugin

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, openldap, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm writing a security plugin for elasticsearch for authentication user for elastic node! I wanna use LDAP for authentication! I set up OpenLDAP on linux but I need some help to config the ldap for injecting credentials into the database and then authenticate user with the server!

I'm writing the program with **java!**

version of *elasticsearch is 6.3.0*
maybe some help
thanks!

Comment: Hello Vahid, and welcome to SO .. please share the code and what you have tried so far, so SO community can help you in a better and faster way.

Comment: hi Hamza! you're right! but i wanna know how can i create an LDAP authentication mechanism in my web service

Comment: @HamzaMohamed did you setup LDAP for ES? If yes - how did you do it? Which steps did you take?

Comment: @Joe No, I went through different path .. I created a nodejs restful app for auth, and dockered both in a closed network.

=>VahidMouasvi sorry for late reply, cannot help you there, just trying to make your 1st question experience more easier for you and the SO community.